# Expression parsing - Possible to get array of property names as string?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, expression-trees, dsl

Is it possible to complete this method? Is it possible in the latest version of C#? Thinking about this as a DSL to configure a system for watching for certain property changes on certain objects.

```
List<string> list = GetProps<AccountOwner>(x => new object[] {x.AccountOwnerName, x.AccountOwnerNumber}); 
// would return "AccountOwnerName" and "AccountOwnerNumber"

public List<string> GetProps<T>(Expression<Func<T, object[]>> exp)
{  
    // code here
}
```

Comment: By 'latest version' you mean 6.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# 6, you'd use:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>
{
    nameof(AccountOwner.AccountOwnerName),
    nameof(AccountOwner.AccountOwnerNumber)
};
```

Before that, you could certainly break the expression tree apart - the easiest way of working out how is probably to either use an expression tree visualizer, or use the code you've got and put a break point in the method (just make it return null for now) and examine the expression tree in the debugger. I'm sure it won't be *very* complicated - just a bit more than normal due to the array.

You could possibly simplify it using an anonymous type, if you use:

```
List<string> list = Properties<AccountOwner>.GetNames(x => new {x.AccountOwnerName, x.AccountOwnerNumber});
```

Then you could have:

```
public static class Properties<TSource>
{
    public static List<string> GetNames<TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> ignored)
    {
        // Use normal reflection to get the properties
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the ordering, you could just use

```
return typeof(TResult).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

If you *do* care about the ordering, you'd need to look at the names the C# compiler gives to the constructor parameters instead - it's a bit ugly. Note that we don't need an expression tree though - we only need the property names from the anonymous type. (An expression tree would work just as well, admittedly.)

Comment: Will `nameof` work for instance properties as well? like `nameof(x.AccountOwnerName)`?

Comment: @haim770: You wouldn't use `x.AccountOwnerName` - you specify the type, because you're trying to tell the compiler which member you're referring to. You're not trying to *access* the properties here.

Comment: I know i'm not trying to access the property, just wondering if it works this way because I want IntelliSense for the property name (when using a lambda for example).

Comment: @haim770: In a lambda expression, you *are* trying to access the property though - that's the difference. Intellisense should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Without c# 6 and nameof, you could get a property name from a expression tree like:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
//...
static string GetNameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
  return (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
```

Using it like:

```
GetNameOf(() => myObject.Property);
```

Not directly usable for an array of objects, but you could make an overload to take an array of expressions... something like:

```
static string[] GetNameOf(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<object>>> properties)
{
  return properties.Select(GetNameOf).ToArray();
}
```

And use it like

```
GetNameOf(
     new Expression<Func<object>>[] 
     { 
       () => x.AccountOwnerName, 
       () => x.AccountOwnerNumber
     }
);
```

Demonstrating fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GsV96t

#### Update

If you go this route, the original `GetNameOf` for a single property won't work for value types (since they get boxed to `object` in the `Expression` and now the expression uses `Convert` internally). This is easily solvable by changing the code to something like:

```
static string GetNameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
  var unary = property.Body as UnaryExpression;
  if (unary != null)
    return (unary.Operand as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
  return (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ToXRuu

*Note: in this updated fiddle I've also updated the overloaded method to return a `List` instead of an array, since that's what was on your original code*

Comment: Let me fire up Visual Studio and try to make a compilable sample. As I said, I did write it off my mind in the Stack Overflow editor :-)

Comment: I've updated the code. No wonder it didn't work, the `Expression<Func<T>>` I was passing in was for an `AccountOwner` expression, but I was passing in expressions of the property types. Shame on me. The edited code works and compiles.